# Click function running on load

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Can anybody tell me why is this click function running on load, I'm running it from wordpress?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.scroll_Top').click(function(e){
        console.log("Hello");   
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have something triggering the `click` event on that element, or perhaps you have some other code somewhere that is logging `Hello`, because your function, as written, won't trigger without the element being clicked on.

I'd make sure you don't have any superfluous event/click handlers on that element in other scripts, as well as make sure `console.log("Hello")` isn't coming from another source (you may want to consider changing your 'diagnostic output' to something more aking to what's actually happening as well. For instance, consider changing your code to `console.log( 'Scroll Top was clicked' )` so you can rule out erroneous event handlers.

Take a look at this example, you'll see both forced console logs run, but your `Hello` isn't logged until the div is clicked - which means you've got something going on elsewhere.

Side note, you may consider [using `.on` instead of `.click`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122078/difference-between-onclick-vs-click).

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    console.log( 'jQuery Loaded' );
    $('.scroll_Top').click(function(e){
        console.log("Hello");   
    });
    console.log( 'Functions defined. Shutting down' );
});
```

```css
.scroll_Top {
  border: 1px solid #0095ee;
  padding: 20px;
}

.scroll_Top:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #0095ee;
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="scroll_Top">Scroll Top (click me)</div>
```

Comment: Thanks mate! but no it's not that, I try the following and its running load

    jQuery(document).foundation();
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('a[href*="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('html, body').animate({
   scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top
  }, 500, 'linear');
    } );
 
    });

Comment: I'm actually using your code, exactly as it is, and it's running on load :(, But "Hello", appears after 'Functions defined. Shutting down'